# How to unerstand the xslt syntax [not(.=preceding::*)]

Tags: xml, xslt

I was looking at an XSLT file created by my colleague, and it contains the following snippet:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@id=&apos;atom6&apos;]/row/DocEntry[not(.=preceding::*)]">
                <DocEntry>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                </DocEntry>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I was having a really hard time trying to understand the part `[not(.=preceding::*]`
After some reading on the usage of the `preceding` anchor, it seems to me that this part doen't do anything at all. Could anybody help me understand what my colleague could possibly be trying to do here?

Comment: He is selecting unique `DocEntry` nodes. `DocEntry[not(.=preceding::*)]` means `DocEntry` node which contents are not equal to any preceding nodes.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen thank you

Comment: See here why this is not a good method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
. = preceding::*
```

is true if the value of the current node is equal to the value of some preceding node. Four concepts you need to understand here, and I'm not sure which of them you are having difficulty with:

- `.` means the current node. You absolutely need to understand this concept to make any sense of XPath at all
- `=` in XPath is a little unusual: it tests whether any of the items on the lhs is equal to any of the items on the rhs, effectively `X = Y` means "some item in X is equal to some item in Y`.
- `preceding::*` selects all elements that precede the current element, in the same document, in document order. In effect given two elements A and B, A precedes B if A's *end* tag appears earlier in the document than B's *start* tag.
- string-value: given an operation like "=" applied to nodes, it actually operates on the string-values of the nodes. For a simple element like `<x>23</x>`, the string value of the element is 23.

So

```
not(. = preceding::*)
```

tests whether the element is different from all previous elements

and

```
//*[not(. = preceding::*)]
```

therefore selects all elements that are not duplicates.

Like most things that are tricky in XSLT 1.0, this of course becomes much easier with XSLT 2.0 - and even if you have the misfortune to be stuck with XSLT 1.0, there are better ways of solving grouping problems using keys.

Comment: The part hard to understand is the unusual `=` part, the fact it means `some item in X is equal to some item in Y` is very unusual indeed.

Comment: It's quite common in the natural language information retrieval tradition, but that's a tradition which many "data processing" folks have never crossed swords with.

Comment: But actually, there are lots of things in XPath that you wouldn't have guessed just by looking at it. You really shouldn't be coding in any language until you've spent a few hours reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following test on xpather.com after reading the comment by [Joel M. Lamsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914902/joel-m-lamsen), it helped me understand the syntax:
[image]